# Как перехватить адреса, посещаемые пользователем?

Tags: c#

Как перехватить все адреса, куда заходит пользователь из браузера? Т.е. нужен по сути файрволл. Как использовать в данном случае TCPListener & HTTPListener?

Comment: Из какого то конкретного браузера или из любого?

Comment: Из любого желательно.

Answer (score 1):

Если требуется из любого браузера, то на C# вам не удастся это сделать. Нужно использовать C++ (или другой native язык) для создания [LSP фильтра](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513664(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: А если использовать API функции для создания чего-то похожего на туннель или работать по типу прокси?

Comment: Прокси (в виде сервиса) можно написать на чем угодно, но тогда нужно чтобы в каждом браузере стоял адрес вашего прокси. А это уже на перехват не очень похоже, поскольку слишком легко обойти.

Comment: А как сделать хотя бы это? Т.е. мне нужен порт, адрес как у прокси и слушатель порта, чтобы проверять адреса входа-выхода юзверя из браузера. т.е. чтобы на запрос типа "http:\\xxx.ru" перекидывало на страницу "Вам туда нельзя!".

Comment: Адрес localhost, порт такой, какой захотите, например, 3128. Создаете Windows-сервис, который будет слушать все входящее по этому порту, затем синтаксически разбирать HTTP протокол (заголовок и сообщение). Если это нормальный адрес, то сами загружаете данные и возвращаете браузеру. Если этот запрос нужно заблокировать, то выдаете заранее подготовленную HTTP страницу - блокировочную страницу. Вот таков алгоритм. А технических проблем и вопросов тут может быть вагон и маленькая тележка.

Comment: Большое спасибо. 
Но нужно все-таки использовать PortListener на определенный порт или HttpListener? Я много читал статей с исходным кодом, но так и не разобрался как работают Listener'ы.

Comment: Как мне кажется, HttpListener вполне подойдет и даже немного упростит работу с запросами.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен фаервол, смотрите в сторону PCAP. По-моему, даже умеет немного фаерволить:) Но перхватывать точно умеет.

Есть библиотеки для C#, писал на нем, реализовал перехват IP-пакетов, но дальше не стал дописывать, было лень. Все пишется очень просто, буквально одной функцией. И вам будут известны все данные об этом соединении. В том числе и адреса. Можно пойти дальше: выдернуть данные (определив предварительно, что инкапсулирована TCP/IP дейтаграмма), снова выдернуть данные, а там уже и до HTTP-данных недалеко, можно будет узнать не только, куда пользователь ходил, а еще и что смотрел! Конечно, для этого нужно исталлировать PCAP, от этого никуда не денешься.

Использование TCP/HTTP-Listener вам не поможет: они не умеют делать то, что вы хотите. Они предназначены для совершенно иных целей.

Comment: Разве библиотека PCAP умеет блокировать нужные запросы? Это же библиотека анализа, а требуется фаервол.

Comment: Да вот как-то я действительно о чем-то другом думал. Вы правы.
По моим представлениям в Windows это будет сделать не так просто.
Я пытался ответить в контексте вопроса.

Есть еще идея, блокировать доступ на уровне ДНС.
OpenDNS имеет такую функцию, можно использовать предустановленные политики (блокировка сайтов эротического содержания и т.п.) и также  в отдельный список можно внести свои сайты, но он ограничен для бесплатного аккаунта. Все что вам надо - зарегистрироваться и прописать ДНС-сервера. Также там будет редирект на страничку о том, что она запрещена для просмотра.

Answer (score -1):

Возьмите WireShark и посмотрите какие пакеты шлет браузер.
И уже по тому что найдете - отлавливайте нужные пакеты и сохраняйте статистику.